# Jetpack compose why viewstate data class

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand why in a lot of Google's official examples, they use Flow combine function to combine from 2-10 different flows into a viewstate data object.
Is there a specific reason to do this? (other than possibly tidier code?)

They even make a boolean that is set in a button onClick into a flow for the sake of making the boolean into that viewstate object. (For example, the selectedCategory variable below is changed in some kind of tabview callback)
Personally I would have made that boolean variable into a MutableState. I don't see why to make it into a flow...

```
data class DiscoverViewState(
    val categories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
    val selectedCategory: Category? = null
)

class DiscoverViewModel(
...
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(DiscoverViewState())
    val state: StateFlow<DiscoverViewState>
        get() = _state
}

@Composable
fun Discover(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val viewModel: DiscoverViewModel = viewModel()
    val viewState by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack Compose is a declarative UI framework for Android that allows you to create composable functions that describe your UI. To manage the UI state, you can use different approaches, such as using remember or rememberSaveable to store local variables, or using ViewModel to store app data that survives configuration changes.

One of the benefits of using ViewModel is that it can hold a ViewState data class that represents the state of your UI at any given moment. A ViewState data class is a simple Kotlin data class that contains all the properties that you need to display in your UI, such as text, images, lists, etc. By using a ViewState data class, you can:

•  Simplify the logic of your composable functions by only depending on one state object instead of multiple variables.

•  Avoid unnecessary recompositions by using StateFlow or LiveData to emit the ViewState only when it changes.

•  Make your code more testable and maintainable by separating the UI state from the business logic.

Checkout this :
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#0